# color nodes based on element of a list of an attribute in igraph

Tags: r, igraph

I've created a network with some nodes and edges.

```
g <- graph.formula(4506-8974, 8974-6345, 7842-4653, 4653-6345, 7842-8974)
V(g)$name <- c("4506", "8974", "6345", "7842", "4653")
```

I'm interested in having the nodes possess a keyword attribute based on my initial `dataframe`. Where `V(g)$keyword` shows the node's keyword. My dataframe took the form of a matrix where the rows are nodes and the columns are keywords. See the example below.

```
df <- data.frame("agriculture" = c(1,1,0,0,0), "arts" = c(0,0,0,1,0), "banks" = c(1,0,1,0,0),
   "cities" = c(0,0,0,1,0), "companies" = c(0,0,0,0,1))
rownames(df) <- c("4506", "8974", "6345", "7842", "4653")


NodeID  agriculture  arts  banks  cities  companies
4506      1          0      1       0        0
8974      1          0      0       0        0
6345      0          0      1       0        0
7842      0          1      0       1        0
4653      0          0      0       0        1
```

I therefore applied this following line of code to create the attribute. Everything works fine so far.

```
V(g)$keyword <- apply(df, 1, function(x) names(df)[x == 1])

V(g)$keyword[1]
#[1] "agriculture" "banks"
V(g)$keyword[2]
#[2] "agriculture"
```

My problem is however when trying to color the nodes based on that specific attribute. Let's say I want to color the nodes that have the keyword "agriculture". The graph will only color node "8974" in red because node "4506" keyword attribute takes the form of a list where both "agriculture" and "banks" are keywords. Hence, it does not consider it. How can I change my code so that the `ifelse` function looks within the list as well?

```
V(g)$color <- ifelse(V(g)$keyword == "agriculture", "red", "blue")
plot(g)
```

Comment: Try `sapply(V(g)$keyword, function(kw) { if ("agriculture" %in% kw) "red" else "blue" })`.

Comment: Thanks Alexis! So just to understand the line of code, what is the function(kw) doing actually?

Comment: `V(g)$keyword` returns a list where each element is a vector of keywords for a given node. The function in `sapply` gets one of those vectors each time, and tests if the word "agriculture" is contained in the vector. See `help("match")`.

Comment: ok got it, thanks. However what is `kw` in `function (kw)`? Don't really understand where that comes from. Could I just just put anything I want in the parenthesis?

Comment: Yes, when you define the function to be applied, you can give any name to the variable, so you could instead write `function(keywords_from_one_vertex) { if ("agriculture" %in% keywords_from_one_vertex)`... if you wanted.